# No access to NTFS section on dual boot after running Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, ntfs

I have 2 operating systems installed (Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10).
There is a section (NTFS) on which I store data (pictures, music, ...).

After running Windows 10, I cannot change the files on this section from Ubuntu (I can from Windows).

How can I fix this?